# Actionscript (2) Question

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

its been ages since i've used flash. What i'm trying to accomplish is use a variable as a trigger for the onRollOver event. The cname variable returns "AUS" however its currently not working. If i use

```
AUS.onRollOver
```

it works

but when i use

```
cname.onRollOver
```

it fails. Sorry for n00b question.

```
this[cname].onRollOver
```

also fails

My Complete Code:

```
function loadXML(loaded) {
    if (loaded) {
        _root.country = this.firstChild.childNodes;
        var cname = country[0].childNodes[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
        var clink = country[0].childNodes[1].firstChild.nodeValue;
        var cregion = country[0].childNodes[2].firstChild.nodeValue;
        var ctext = country[0].childNodes[3].firstChild.nodeValue;

        trace(cname);
        trace(clink);
        trace(cregion);
        trace(ctext);

        this[cname].onRollOver = function() {
            var colorful = new Color(this);
            colorful.setRGB(0x0099d9);
            subline.text = ctext;
        };
        this[cname].onRollOut = function() {
            var colorful = new Color(this);
            colorful.setRGB(0x939598);
            subline.text = "";
        };
        this[cname].onRelease = function(){
            getURL(clink, _self);
        }
    } else {
        content = "file not loaded!";
    }
}
xmlData = new XML();
xmlData.ignoreWhite = true;
xmlData.onLoad = loadXML;
xmlData.load("countries.xml");
```

my complete xml (countries.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<countries>
    <country>
        <name>AUS</name>
        <hyperlink>http://www.google.com.au/</hyperlink>
        <region>australasia</region>
        <infotext>Welcome to Australia</infotext>
    </country>
    <country>
        <name>USA</name>
        <hyperlink>http://www.google.com/</hyperlink>
        <region>australasia</region>
        <infotext>Welcome to America</infotext>
    </country>
</countries>
```

Answer (score 0):

this[cname].onRollOver = //some callback function